# Console Application Prestart

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, console-application, custom-attributes

Is there any attribute similar to WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod (webActivatorEx dll) for console applications implemented in .NET 4.5 . Or is it possible to create one? I would like to create an attribute, that will make a method execute before the console application's main method is executed. I would not like to use Postsharp or any similar library that does not come with the .NET 4.5 framework.

Comment: What are you going to achieve? You can use static constructor. It will be executed before main method. Will it solve your problem? Link to msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa645612(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you @Yury Kerbitskov, but this does not solve my problem. A static constructor is executed, when a static property/method is access from the static class, but not before the Main function of a console application. I would like something that is executed before the Main function, if that is possible.

Comment: the main method is accessed via the class so the static construct must have run.

Comment: why not modify the `Main`?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way you can do this without having to modify the `Main` function itself or at least the class which contains the `Main` function.

I don't see why you would want to do this. Why not simply add some code to the start of your `Main`? Perhaps you could be more specific in your question with regards to what exactly you are trying to achieve.

### Static constructor

The simplest way I could think of is to create a static constructor for the class which contains the `Main` method. That will be executed before the Main method is called.

### Custom attribute

You **can** create a custom attribute, but it won't work without you writing some code that explicitly searches for stuff that has that attribute. See the MSDN articles on [writing custom attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx) and [retrieving information stored in attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct(v=vs.110).aspx).

So an attribute doesn't actually do anything by itself. In order for it to work, you need to use Reflection. The [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx/) works the same way: the framework explicitly searches for this attribute and executes the method through Reflection.

If this is what you want to do, you need to:

- Create a custom attribute
- Write some code in your `Main` that looks for that attribute and executes the method specified.

Although I don't see why you would need such a thing in a console app.